# Setting the value of one column of all rows is very slow

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

I have a table containing about 350 000 rows, and I have recently changed from MyISAM storage engine to InnoDB.

I run query

```
UPDATE `users` SET `online` = 0
```

every time my server starts, and there was no issues at all when using MyISAM. The query usually affects only a couple of hundred of rows. The execution time for the query was slow, about 1.5 seconds on average, but something I could live with.

Now that I've changed to InnoDB, the query can, however, take tens of seconds to finish.

Here's part of mysql-slow.log

```
# Query_time: 29.431546  Lock_time: 0.000091 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 348617
SET timestamp=1372505574;
UPDATE users SET online = 0;
```

This particular query change the online value for 200 rows, others were already 0.

I was able to solve the issue by changing the query to

```
UPDATE `users` SET `online` = 0 WHERE `online` != 0
```

This query took about 0.1 seconds

Now, here's my question. why does the time increase so significantly when changing from MyISAM to InnoDB?

And how come the query is so slow without the WHERE part? As far as I've understood, MySQL's query optimiser is quite powerful, but this suggests the opposite. What could be causing this very slow query execution time?

The MySQL server version is 5.5.31-0.

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In InnoDB, `update` statements lock every row they scan. This means that to update your 200 rows, it have to create 350 000 row-level locks, while keeping a rollback lock at the same time and providing the previous value to any transactions that are reading the already changed value (since the transaction is not committed and the change is not final)

MyISAM on the other hand locks the entire table.

So if you need to update all of the rows, lock the entire table, and you'll get a far better performance (you won't need the row-level locks)

But even better, provide a WHERE clause, like you did, and InnoDB will acquire locks only for the matching rows (as well as some gap-locks in the index tree, but this is out of the scope of the question)

Answer (score 2):

InnoDB implements transaction semantics. That is, it does extensive work to project to other readers of your table the illusion that your `online` column values all change to zero at precisely the same instant. It also is a capable, if your client or the server crashes, of automatically rolling back the values to the *status quo ante.*  MyISAM doesn't care about this.  It is a lot of work for a table with hundreds of thousands of rows.

It doesn't care that the values are already zero. It changes them anyhow.

When you use the `WHERE` clause you're changing a whole lot fewer rows, so its transaction logic has a whole lot less work to do.

This transaction logic is a critical feature. You were using it in an edge-case way for which it's not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

you should better rewrite the query to from

```
UPDATE `users` SET `online` = 0 WHERE `online` != 0
```

to

```
UPDATE `users` SET `online` = 0 WHERE `online` = 1
```

indexes can a better looked up when using a = vs !=

Check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31088/4
And onfold there "View Execution Plan" to see wants going on here

```
!= triggers a range 
= triggers a ref which should perform better
```

As a side note you normally should not index colums with a bad selectivity