# Update column to 1 if value is highest in group, 0 otherwise

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table with following columns:

```
player_id, datetime, player_level, is_latest
```

What I need to do, is to set `is_latest = 1`, when `datetime` is highest for the player.

This is how I would check highest datetime for players:

```
SELECT player_id, MAX(datetime)
FROM players
GROUP BY player_id
```

And now I need to update whole table:

```
UPDATE players
SET is_latest = /* 1 if datetime = MAX(datetime), 0 otherwise */
```

Do you have any ideas how to write `UPDATE` statement? Best if I could have `SELECT` and `UPDATE` in single SQL query.

The table has 30 millions of rows, so I would like a solution that doesn't involve copying all rows somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's the fastest way, but this query should do what you want and give you an idea about the general syntax:

```
UPDATE players p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT player_id, MAX(datetime) max_date
  FROM players
  GROUP BY player_id
) t ON p.player_id = t.player_id AND p.datetime = t.max_date
SET p.is_latest = (t.max_date IS NOT NULL);
```

Using a `left join` means that rows that don't match the `p.datetime = t.max_date` predicate will be `null`, a fact that we can use in a boolean expression in the `set` clause to ensure that only the latest rows will be set to one and the older will be set to 0.

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36f97/1) for an example.

As always, when it comes to testing updates and such, make sure to have a copy/backup...

Comment: But if I inserted new rows to `players` table with higher datetime, your solution wouldn't reset `is_latest` back to zero for appropriate rows.

Comment: @stil Oh, true. I missed that part of the requirement. I'll fix my answer later - in a rush at the moment. It should be doable using a left join and a case statement.

Comment: @stil I've update my answer now. If changing the `is_latest` flag is something you want to happen every time you insert a row you should look into triggers instead. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: It worked, but took 70 minutes for 10 million rows table. Ridiculously slow.

Comment: @stil It might be slow due to bad or missing indexes; you could try to do explain and see how the query is treated. 70 minutes sounds excessive. Might be a locking issue if you have other users accessing the table.

Comment: This is probably a reason of slowness: [Setting the value of one column of all rows is very slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379801/setting-the-value-of-one-column-of-all-rows-is-very-slow). I added to SQL code: `WHERE p.is_latest = (t.max_date IS NULL);`. First run: `Query OK, 7515294 rows affected (1 hour 30 min 11.61 sec)`, second run: `Query OK, 0 rows affected (8 min 29.29 sec)` (on 36 million row table)